# How can I manipulate, and bind functions to, cloned elements effectively?

Tags: jquery

My HTML code:

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
<div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
        <div>
            <select id="sistem1">
                <option class="blank" value="">Select a car</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select id="sub_sistem1">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select id="child_sub_sistem1">
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
```

To add(clone) new field, i use this jquery:

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
$(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    var obj = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').end().find('option').removeAttr('selected').focus();
});
$('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
        $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
}); });
```

The problem is when i click 'add field', all cloned/added element still using the same ID `(sistem1, sub_sistem1,child_sub_sistem1)`, 
how to make cloned/added element has unique ID, example `(sistem2, sub_sistem2,child_sub_sistem2)`, `(sistem3, sub_sistem3,child_sub_sistem3)`?


To chain select, i use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select#sistem1").change(function() {
    var id = $("select#sistem1 option:selected").attr('value');
    $.post("core/select_sub_sistem.php", {
        id: id
    }, function(data) {
        $("select#child_sub_sistem1").empty();
        $("select#sub_sistem1").html(data);
    });
});
$("select#sub_sistem1").change(function() {
    var id = $("select#sub_sistem1 option:selected").attr('value');
    $.post("core/select_child_sub_sistem.php", {
        id: id
    }, function(data) {
        $("select#child_sub_sistem1").html(data);
    });
}); });
```

If I add/clone field using my code above, when i select an option, all cloned/added field will be changed too, how to prevent his?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is, **don't**. Anything that can be done with incremental `ids` can be done with classes and a given index with greater simplicity (IMHO).

For example, if you want to do something with the second select box in the second group you can do so using the element's class and jQuery's .eq()  (example in code below):

As far as how you create your clones and attach your handlers, the process can be greatly simplified like:

```js
$(function() {
  $multiFieldWrapper=$('.multi-field-wrapper');
  $multiFields = $('.multi-fields');
  $multiFields.data('cachedMultiField', $multiFields.html());
  $multiFieldWrapper.on('click', '.add-field', function() {
    $multiFields.append($multiFields.data('cachedMultiField'));
  });
  $multiFieldWrapper.on('click', '.remove-field', function() {
    $(this).closest('.multi-field').remove();
  });
  $multiFieldWrapper.on('change', '.sistem', function() {
    var cur=$multiFieldWrapper.find('.sistem').index($(this));
    $.post("core/select_sub_sistem.php", {
        id: this.value
    }, function(data) {
        $('.child_sub_sistem').eq(cur).empty();
       $('.sub_sistem').html(data);
    });
  });
  $multiFieldWrapper.on('change', '.sub_sistem', function() {
    var cur=$multiFieldWrapper.find('.sub_sistem').index($(this));
    $.post("core/select_child_sub_sistem.php", {
        id: this.value
    }, function(data) {
        $('.child_sub_sistem').eq(cur).html(data);
    });
  });

  // simulate adding an group
  $('.add-field').click();
  // add option to second select in second group
  $('.sub_sistem').eq(1).append('<option>Added option</option>');
});
```

```html
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
    <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">
            <div>
                <select class="sistem">
                    <option class="blank" value="">Select a car</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select class="sub_sistem">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select class="child_sub_sistem">
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @wawanmadda Curious, what was the bug?

Comment: when we select an option in 'sub_sistem', the value retrieved from database is placed at the same class 'sub_sistem', so i change the code  $('.sub_sistem').eq(cur).html(data); to  $('.child_sub_sistem').eq(cur).html(data); now its work (y)

Comment: Example i add new field [pic1](http://s1.postimg.org/uu6u30yyn/Capture21.png) , and then i choose 1 option at class 'sistem', all another 'sub_sistem' will  display value retrieved from database [pic2](http://s1.postimg.org/h0izkvzsv/Capture22.png) , how to fix this so it doesnt trigger another 'sub_sistem' when selecting option in 'sistem'?

Comment: @wawanmadda Ah, gotcha, yeah I missed that one. Updated : )